# .loc has no attribute error when run a defined process for all files in a directory

Tags: python, pandas

I have a defined process as below.

```
def process(df):

    date = df.loc[0,'month']

    for i in df.index:
        if pd.isnull(df.loc[i, 'month'])==True:
            df.loc[i, 'month'] = date
        else: 
            date = df.loc[i, 'month']
```

I could run it for one excel file, however when I used:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    process(file)
```

I have the Error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
>   Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: `process` expects a dataframe, so why are you passing it a filepath?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need create `DataFrame` from file, e.g. by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then for replace `NaN`s is faster and better use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
def process(df):
    date = df.loc[0,'month']
    df['month'] = df['month'].fillna(date)
    return df

for file in os.listdir(directory): 
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    process(df)
```